# Did Lord Vishnu fight battles in the company of Indra Deva?

Tags: vedas, vishnu, indra, vedic-gods

Rig veda describes Lord Vishnu as an ally of Indra dev, so is there any story where they have fought battles together or is it an indication to Vamana avatar?

Comment: Related [Are some richas in Rigveda dedicated to Vishnu from Adityas and not from Trinity?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/22677/are-some-richas-in-rigveda-dedicated-to-vishnu-from-adityas-and-not-from-trinity)