# Are some richas in Rigveda dedicated to Vishnu from Adityas and not from Trinity?

Tags: vishnu, bhagavad-gita, rig-veda

Vishnu is in Adityas (sons of Aditi) too.

**Bhagavad Gita 10.21**

> आदित्यानामहं विष्णुर्ज्योतिषां रविरंशुमान्।
>   मरीचिर्मरुतामस्मि नक्षत्राणामहं शशी।।10.21।।
>
> **Of the sons of Aditi, I am Vishnu**; of the luminaries, the radiant Sun; of the Maruts, I am Marici; of the stars, I am the Moon.

Vamana (an incarnation of Lord Vishnu) is Aditya (son of Aditi) or Upendra (younger brother of Indra). Vishnu is mentioned in Adityas in [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21768/names-of-adityas-and-saptarishi) question's answer too.

In Rigveda, as more preference is given to 33 koti (type) Devas (12 Adityas, 8 Vasus, 11 Rudras, 2 Ashvins (or Prajapati and Indra in another list) and their family) and not to the Trinity directly (I mean preference is given via a post named Prajapati (to Bhrahma) and Rudra (an incarnation of Lord Shiva)).

**So, are there some richas of Rigveda dedicated to Vishnu who is from Adityas and not from Trinity?**

English translation of [Rigveda 1.22.18](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv01022.htm) might be talking about Vamana (from Adityas) but not sure. Are there any other richas, as one member of this user has asked [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/22390/why-is-lord-vishnu-referred-to-as-upendra-in-the-vedas) and [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/22400/is-indra-the-chief-god-of-the-vedas) question which means there must be some richas which are dedicated to Vishnu from Adityas or **Vishnu from Adityas is mentioned in richas which are dedicated to Indra.**

And another user of this site [replied](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/22400/is-indra-the-chief-god-of-the-vedas#comment65226_22400) to my comment on [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/22400/is-indra-the-chief-god-of-the-vedas) that "if it's mentioned as Vishnu in the Vedas then it has to be Vishnu only, if it was Vamana then they could have said Vamana",

**What will be the interpretation of Bhagavad Gita 10.21, is this Vishnu from Trinity or Vishnu's incarnation as a son of Aditi?**

Comment: Yes it seems true

Answer (score 2):

The questions are:

> - are there some richas of Rigveda dedicated to Vishnu who is from Adityas and not from Trinity?
> - What will be the interpretation of Bhagavad Gita 10.21, is this Vishnu from Trinity or Vishnu's incarnation as a son of Aditi?

---

- The Trinity concept of Puranas,ie., Brahma , Vishnu and Shiva cannot be found in the Veda.
- Aditi, the mother of Gods, which include Vishnu also, was mentioned so in Rig Veda [II.27.7](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv02027.htm)

> ***Mother of Kings, may Aditi*** transport us, by fair paths Aryaman, beyond
>   all hatred. May we uninjured, girt by many heroes, win Varuṇa's and
>   Mitra's high protection.

- So Vishnu is one of the Adityas
- Agni, Indra, Vishnu, etc, are the epithets used in Rig Veda to denote the Almighty. So whatever richas are there for Agni or Indra or Brihaspati, etc, are applicable to Vishnu also.

Rig Veda [II.1.3](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv02001.htm) says

> Hero of Heroes, Agni! Thou art **Indra**, thou art **Viṣṇu** of the Mighty
>   Stride, adorable: Thou, **Brahmaṇaspati**, the Brahman finding wealth:
>   thou, O Sustainer, with thy wisdom tendest us.

- However, there are a few richas for Vishnu also.  You can check [here](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv07099.htm) and [here](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv07100.htm).

---

Comment: If trinity concept is not there, then what Vedas says about creation and nourishment and destruction? I am sure about Rudra being destroyer as per Vedas. What about other twos?

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto: Apart from Rudra, Indra and Brihaspati were also described to have used weapons.  In Rig Veda, many words were used in esoteric sense only, but should not be understood in literal sense.

Comment: Oh so you mean for any act of God be it creation or nourishment or destruction are attributed to other Gods as well and hence no Trinity concept. Did I understand correctly?

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto: Yes, but not to other Gods.  Those were the epithets of the Same God.  In respect of protection, the God was called Indra, in respect of wisdom, it is called brihaspati, etc.

Comment: Oh thank you. much clear now. 

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely no that is the form of god we know that lord rudra as a partial incration of lord shiva samely lord vishnu may be a form of lord narayana.

The harivamsa of mahabharat gives
an thought on this :-

> yathA jale jalaM kShiptaM jalameva
>   tu tadbhavet |rudraM viShNuH
>   praviShTastu tathArudramayo
>   bhavet ||2-125-33
>
> As water that falls on water
>   becomes water, when viShNu
>   enters rudra (shiva), he (viShNu)
>   will become full of rudra (shiva).
>
> agnimagniH praviShTastu agnireva
>   yathA bhavet |tathA viShNuM
>   praviShTastu rudro viShNumayo
>   bhavet ||2-125-34
>
> As fire that enters fire becomes
>   fire, when rudra (shiva) enters
>   viShNu, he (rudra, shiva) will
>   become full of viShNu.

there was a movement when arjun asked krishna who are you when he taken his form after vishwrupa the distruction form then god told i am Mahakaal came for distruction of worlds.

so in whole name of lord shiva and lord narayana didn't occoured but lord shankara from 11 rudras and lord vishnu from 12 adityas occoured they are incration of god shiva and god narayana.

see here:—

> O son of Pritha, flowed from this
>   Krishna who is Vishwaksena. The
>   Rudras, the Adityas, the Vasus, the
>   Aswins, the Sadhyas, the
>   Viswedevas, the diverse Maruts,
>   Prajapati himself, the mother of
>   the deities, viz., Aditi, and the
>   seven Rishis, have all sprung from
>   Krishna.
>
> —The Mahabharata, Book 13:
>   Anusasana Parva: Section CLVIII

See rudras are said to sprung from
krishna. Because both lord narayan
and lord shiva are said to create
The Rudras, the Adityas, the Vasus,
the Aswins, the Viswedevas etc.

> Eleven hundred Rudras stood
>   around that Deity of restrained
>   soul and white deeds, then seated
>   upon his bull. All of them were
>   employed in hymning his praises.
>   The Adityas, the Vasus, the
>   Sadhyas, the Viswedevas, and the
>   twin Aswins praised that Lord of
>   the universe by uttering the hymns
>   occurring in the scriptures.
>
> —— The Mahabharata, Book 13:
>   Anusasana Parva: Anusasanika
>   Parva: Section XIV

Rigveda talks about truth and we know that rigveda talk about lord vishnu only not about lord vamana even in vedas lord vishnu is **not an aditya**.

In vedas i don't think there is mention of 33 gods.

There was itself a vedic trinity of agni, vayu,surya.— https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trimurti

Comment: So r u saying that in Rigveda, Lord Vishnu is neither Vamana nor Aditya... and still Upendra (junior to Indra or younger brother of Indra)???

Comment: he is not said upendra in vedas @YDS

Comment: only  aranyakas or brahmanas may say this.

Comment: did u go through the questions which I linked in my question's body... This question is follow up question for those questions...

Comment: I gone through and valmiki ramayana said lord vishnu as upendra and mahemdra but that again i am saying not in vedas after vedas this became popular just before that lord rudra was also unborn same as lord vishnu after that there were two forms of lord rudra one born to prajapati and one immortal.
— http://sacred-texts.com/hin/sbr/sbe43/sbe4330.htm
i am just saying that vedas do not call lord vishnu not as an aditya and uoendra but just as a friend to indra who helps him.

Comment: but those questions say that Vishnu is referred as Aditya and Upendra...we can't discard something blindly..here, I m not looking an answer from Wikipedia but after compilation of atleast all the richas of Rigveda dedicated to Vishnu and Indra...

Comment: no wikipedia here i am saying it because he is never reffred in so the vedic adityas are not even 12 friend.
you can check vedic verses too if you want in hymns dedicated to adityas. Vishnu is not an aditya in vedas.

Comment: http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv02027.htm

http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv10072.htm

check all now i am not giving wikipedia link now i am giving solid refrences from wikipedia check these are hymns to adityas and they are 7 one is not counted or leaved
The eighth Âditya ( Mārtanda)
was rejected by Aditi, thus
leaving only seven sons. — https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Âdityas

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/11416/7853

Comment: @Rakesh joshi i mentioned that lord vishnu is not called an aditya in vedas but in aranyakas and brahmanas it exists.

Comment: @Fiercelord so you accept that only samhitas are vedas ? Good

Comment: those are commentries on them attached to samhitas may be like upnishads but the real veda is i think samhitas.

Comment: May be u would like to see https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17417/is-vishnu-a-vedic-deity-are-there-any-mantras-attributed-to-him and https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/6870/how-has-lord-vishnus-understanding-developed-and-what-was-his-role-initially

Comment: i am not understanding i am just saying that the gods in vedas are bit diffrent in details in after that i only said that lord vishnu as not any sub-ordinate or younger brother to indra in vedas but in aranyakas,brahmanas and later on whats wrong here.??